# Iterating through 2 arrays in javascript (gsap)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, gsap

I am having trouble iterating through 2 arrays to change my gsap timeline.

```
const subTabs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".subtab"));
const expandTabs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".expandtab"));
const tl = gsap.timeline({ defaults: { duration: 1, yoyo: true, } });

tl.set(expandTabs, {
    visibility: "hidden",
    opacity: 0,
    scale: 0,
});
```

I need the index values to correspond, for example, if subTabs[0] is "mouseover" then expandTabs[0] needs to have the new animations applied to it. Vice versa with "mouseout". What am I doing wrong here?

```
subTabs.forEach((subTab, index) => {
    const expandTab = expandTabs[index];
    console.log(subTab, expandTab);

    // Event Listener Hover on
    subTab.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
        console.log("you clicked region number " + index);
        tl.to(expandTab[index], {
            visibility: "visible",
            opacity: 1,
            scale: 1,
        });
    });

    // Event Listener Hover off
    subTab.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
        console.log("you exited region number " + index);
        tl.to(expandTab[index], {
            visibility: "hidden",
            opacity: 0,
            scale: 0,
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to do the following: subTabs[index].addEventListener ... ?

Comment: yes, this gives 'gsap target undefined not found'. Is this because of expandTab in tl.to()?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like you should use expantTabs[index] in tl.to(). You are missing a "s" (expandTab[index] should be expandTabs[index] I guess).

Comment: On one line you have const expandTab = expandTabs[index]; then later you do expandTab[index], which is basically expandTabs[index][index].  Looks like a bug.

Comment: Ok I fixed it, the array is pulling class elements from inline svg paths and it was the way the svg was optimized. Designer had elements hidden in illustrator and this was causing issue after the fix. expandTabs[index] is the solution. Thank you!!!

Comment: @James Correct, thank you also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your second listener should be `mouseout` instead of another `mouseover`.

```js
subTab.addEventListener("mouseout", (event) => {
```

In regards to the index issue, why not used an generated `id` instead to retrieve the element?

As is, your line here might work better as:

```js
tl.to(expandTab, {
            visibility: "visible",
            opacity: 1,
            scale: 1,
        });
```

Comment: Yes, haha I have changed this code quite a few times trying different methods...